# Ошибка при создании QfileDialog по нажатию кнопки для выбора файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton, qfiledialog

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки **`browse_2`** вылизало диалоговое окно выбора файла, но увы выдает ошибку.

ОШИБКА:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mazafaker/python/SUPER PROJECT v228/project stegano/main.py", line 76, in clicker
    res = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'jpg')
TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', initialFilter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

Process finished with exit code
```

Помогите.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# импортируемые модули для проекта
import time
import os,sys
import pathlib
import wave
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import shutil
from math import ceil
from subprocess import call,STDOUT
from tqdm import tqdm
from stegano import lsb
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 241, 17))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.browse_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browse_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 130, 89, 25))
        self.browse_2.setObjectName("browse_2")
        self.browse_2.findChild(QPushButton, 'browse_2')
        self.browse_2.clicked.connect(self.clicker)
        self.progressBar_2 = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 371, 23))
        self.progressBar_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.progressBar_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar_2.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar_2.setObjectName("progressBar_2")
        self.logo_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 0, 251, 81))
        self.logo_2.setText("")
        self.logo_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./logo.png"))
        self.logo_2.setObjectName("logo_2")
        self.filename_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.filename_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 221, 25))
        self.filename_2.setObjectName("filename_2")
        self.btnencrypt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnencrypt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 190, 131, 41))
        self.btnencrypt_2.setObjectName("btnencrypt_2")
        self.btncrypt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btncrypt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 131, 41))
        self.btncrypt_2.setObjectName("btncrypt_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 377, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Укажите путь к файлу:"))
        self.browse_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор..."))
        self.btnencrypt_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровать"))
        self.btncrypt_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зашифровать"))

    def clicker(self):
        res = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', './', 'jpg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Класс QFileDialog предоставляет диалоговое окно, позволяющее пользователям выбирать файлы или каталоги. Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html

```
import sys
'''
import os
import time
import pathlib
import wave
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import shutil
from math import ceil
from subprocess import call,STDOUT
from tqdm import tqdm
from stegano import lsb
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog, \
    QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 241, 17))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt \"Ubuntu\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.browse_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.browse_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 130, 89, 25))
        self.browse_2.setObjectName("browse_2")
        self.browse_2.findChild(QPushButton, 'browse_2')
#        self.browse_2.clicked.connect(self.clicker)
        self.progressBar_2 = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 250, 371, 23))
        self.progressBar_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.progressBar_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.progressBar_2.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar_2.setObjectName("progressBar_2")
        self.logo_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.logo_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 0, 251, 81))
        self.logo_2.setText("")
        self.logo_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./logo.png"))
        self.logo_2.setObjectName("logo_2")
        self.filename_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.filename_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 221, 25))
        self.filename_2.setObjectName("filename_2")
        self.btnencrypt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnencrypt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 190, 131, 41))
        self.btnencrypt_2.setObjectName("btnencrypt_2")
        self.btncrypt_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btncrypt_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 131, 41))
        self.btncrypt_2.setObjectName("btncrypt_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 377, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Укажите путь к файлу:"))
        self.browse_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обзор..."))
        self.btnencrypt_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровать"))
        self.btncrypt_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зашифровать"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # !!! тут ваша логика 
        
        self.browse_2.clicked.connect(self.clicker)           # !!!

    def clicker(self):                                        # !!!
        res, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Open File', 
            './', 
            '(*.jpg)'                                         # !!!
        )
        if res:
            self.filename_2.setText(res)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `def clickerbrowse(self):
        res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', './')
        self.filename_2.setText(res[0])`

убрал self и заработало, но я пошел вашим методом создал новый класс, спасибо за объяснение